# Push notification on browser does't work when the tab closed

Tags: javascript, push-notification

On browsers,I'm trying to send push notification even if the tab is closed, actually i could't found any of answers that help.
how facebook send notification if the tab is closed?

i have written this code, it works only if the tab is active

```
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
            }
        });
    }

    setTimeout(next, 1000*10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use google gcm push notifications to send notification even when the website is not opened.

Its quite simple, follow the instructions in https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client

Note: HTTPS is necessary for it.

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately my website is not https protocol in the other hand i need to make it work with firefox also

Comment: Then i would suggest you to take a third party service like https://onesignal.com/webpush or https://pushcrew.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Google GCM has been discontinued but it's been replaced with Google firebase. It's available on Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari, and edge (I believe).

Comment: The question was 8 years ago